Tailwind CSS alternatives for Angular :host pseudo-class selector
I started using Tailwind CSS in an Angular project and I'm having some issues trying to find a clean way to replace my css styling rules that are using Angular's :host selector.
Couldn't find anything specific for this in the documentation and so far I could only see a reference to the @apply directive that would work like the following:
// before tailwind css
:host {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
// after tailwind css
:host {
  @apply tracking-normal whitespace-nowrap;
}

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Just out of curiosity, why do you want to use Tailwind? Why not keep using native CSS rules?

Tailwind doesn't work well within a shadow DOM since Shadow DOM can't be styled from the outside. The elements inside shadow DOM that uses tailwind class won't even work unless you duplicate the styles into the shadow DOM like what you did.

@SyndRain I didn't duplicate the styles and it seems to work just fine with the usage of the @apply directive, so I'm not sure if I understood your point correctly...

@HostBinding() protected readonly class = ''tailwind-class-1 tailwind-class-2"; does the trick ... you can do it in the host section in the declaration above the class as well.

@ThomasRenger I tried that and in fact the class is applied in the html but it's not processed by tailwind...

Check your setup if you configured html files only. Tailwind uses the usage of the classes to define the final style file, but if you set it up for html files only these classes are missing in the final file.

Example for the tailwind.config.js (only a part):
content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"]

You're right! I had an extra whitespace between html and the ts in the setup config. Thanks!
